# Access/modify AppDelegate in Xcode during UI Testing

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode-ui-testing

The preliminary skeleton generated when creating a new target for UI testing in Xcode 7 looks like:

```
    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()

        // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.

        // In UI tests it is usually best to stop immediately when a failure occurs.
        continueAfterFailure = false
        // UI tests must launch the application that they test. Doing this in setup will make sure it happens for each test method.
        XCUIApplication().launch()

        // In UI tests it’s important to set the initial state - such as interface orientation - required for your tests before they run. The setUp method is a good place to do this.
    }
```

I have an `AppDelegate` that uses a service provider to access various repositories, like a `UserService` for looking up users, etc.

I have, in my unit test bundle, a `MockUserService` that allows direct manipulation of the underlying data for testing scenarios. **One** solution is to add this to the main app bundle, and have the AppDelegate check the launch environment, and assign the `Mock` implementation given some testing flag/environment variable. The *downside* here is that I'd have to ship my `Mock` implementations with the app - so no go.

I would *like* to, in the above `setUp()` method, do something like:

```
XCUIApplication().delegate.serviceProvider = MockServiceProvider()
```

But I can't seem to find an easy way to access the application delegate during UI testing, to get it into a "testable" state.

How can the delegate, or any portion of the underlying app, be accessed/modified at this stage?

Comment: I would like to know this as well, in normal unit tests the apps code is available but in UI testing it can't seem to access things like the appDelegate

Comment: Athough it's not he solution you want, can't you create a second target for your app, only include the Mock in that target, then ifdef the mock in your app delegate and test that target? Then you don't have to ship the mock. Not a very clean solution of course..

Comment: @Brynjar That's one solution, yea. The downsides (aside from the obvious ones) are that the test *target* is then driving the entire test *suite*. What if for a particular unit test, I only want to mock one service? And for another test, I want to mock *three* services? This would require a new target for each mock "permutation", when ideally I'd be able to drive the mock-ness from the *test itself*.